# how to resolve Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Tags: php, oop, static-methods

I want to use value of a static variable as value of another static variable

But it is not working.

For ex.

```
class Gateway
{

    public static $config = [
        'key0' => 0,
        'key1' => 1
    ];

    public static $another_config = [
        self::$config['key0'],
        self::$config['key1'],
    ];

    private function __construct()
    {
        //something here
    }

}
```

How can I do that or any alternative of this?

Comment: "*It is not working*" is not particularly descriptive. How do you know it's not working? Is there an error thrown? Show us what you expected vs. what actually occurred.

Comment: You can't.  It must be a constant expression that doesn't change at runtime.

Comment: I suspect it doesn't have anything to do with static variables but with using complex code in a class property definition. But you should be getting some fatal error.

Comment: @esqew
Severity: Compile Error

Message: Constant expression contains invalid operations